# So i am trying to match a number and a name.Can you explain the meaning of this symbol in this code? The question is inside the comments

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
my_array=[1,2,3]

my_array1=['John','Tom','Peter']

search=int(input("Enter your number"))

for i in range(0,3):
    if search==my_array[i]: ### can you please point out the purpose of this '[i]' ? what does it do? 
            print(my_array1[i]) ### also this one
```

Comment: See the tutorials on lists here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: `my_array[i]` is accessing an element of `my_array` by position. for example, `my_array[0]` returns the first element of the list (counting starts at 0, not 1 here).

Comment: @G.Anderson This post doesn't use slices, does it?

Comment: Still valid as an extension of indexing notation IMO

Comment: I'm voting to close this, it's a trivial question which is unlikely to benefit future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_array1` is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). This list holds three elements, `'John'` as the first element, `'Tom'` as the second element and `'Peter'` as the third element. In this case, the elements are [strings](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp), but list can hold any type of elements, like for example `my_array` which contains integers. When you want to do stuff with an element in a list, you need a way to access this element. You access an element in a list with the square brackets `[]` and the position of the element in the list. It is important to note, that the numbering of element starts at 0. So the first element, `'John'` is at position 0 in the list. To access it, you write `my_array1[0]`. Similarly, to access the second and third element, you write `my_array1[1]` and `my_array1[2]`.

Now to answer your question: `i` is nothing more than a substitution for any number, in your program for the numbers 0, 1 or 2. So if `i` is 1, writing `my_array1[i]` is the same as writing `my_array1[1]` and accesses the second element in `my_array1`, which is `'Tom'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood about accessing an element in a list but I was not clear why 'i' was in there but I get it now. Thank you.